# Specifying a local html file as <licenseUrl> in .nuspec

Tags: nuget, licensing, nuget-package, nuspec

I am trying to create a NuGet package and in the .nuspec file, I am trying to use a local license file instead of license URL as required by  tag in the .nuspec file. Is there a way to achieve this? Is having license URL mandatory for creating licensed packages?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the file URI schema  **file://host/path**

**Example**:
file:///D:/Company/Projects/Framework/Main/SharedSources/CompanyLicense.txt

Comment: Even though I can point to a file this way and Visual Studio isn't complaining, I cannot view the license.